# Is there a way to check if a fmt::output_file has been opened successfully for writing

Tags: c++, error-handling, ostream, fmt

I'm trying to use [`fmt::output_file`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#system-apis) and am looking for a way to check if the file has been opened successfully for writing.
Is this possible? What's the idiomatic way to do this?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d8xb8hn7E)

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, `fmt::output_file` will open the file with `sopen_s` on Windows and `open` on other systems. If the file cannot open to write, it will throw an `std::system_error`. And you can retrieve the return code with [`std::system_error::code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/code) if needed.

---

Note, by default, `fmt::output_file` will open the file with `file::WRONLY | file::CREATE | file::TRUNC` flags. To make sure it doesn't create a file if the given path does not exist, you should manually pass a flag without `file::CREATE`:

```cpp
fmt::output_file(file_name, fmt::file::WRONLY | fmt::file::TRUNC);
```

Comment: @ridilculous Note by default, `output_file` will open with flags `file::WRONLY | file::CREATE | file::TRUNC`. To make sure it doesn't create a file if not exist, you need to manually pass a flag without `file::CREATE`.